# Changes to HTML files not showing on built phonegap 3.0 app

Tags: eclipse, cordova

So I have a Phonegap 3.0 app (`project` folder), and it's project (`project/platforms/android`) on Eclipse.

The problem is that when I change `project/www/index.html` , and tell Eclipse to Run the project, the changes don't appear on my device.

I noticed that Eclipse was saying `Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.` so I tried adding a space in a .java file so that Eclipse would notice some change in the project and rebuild it. It worked, `Installing RingTo.apk... Success!` showed on the log, but still the changes to `index.html` didn't show at the device...

Comment: Please clean project and install again

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, actually, @Lizzie the problem was that phonegap creates one www folder for each platform, and neither of them point to the one nearest the root. So I ended up creating hardlinks to solve the problem...

Comment: I actually found the solution later. Wait till I right a complete answer

Comment: *write a complete answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes made to the files inside ***project/www/*** are not automatically copied to your project (in your case to ***project/platforms/android/assets/www/***). You have to run the following command to iteratively copy the changes to platform specific projects and build them. Open the command prompt and navigate to the root of the project (In this case ***project/***). Or you can even right click on the ***project/*** folder while pressing the shift key. Then run the following command:

```
cordova build
```

You can optionally limit the scope of each build to specific platforms:

```
cordova build android
```

Alternatively, you can run the following commands:

```
cordova prepare android
cordova compile android
```

In this case, once you run prepare, you can use Eclipse with ADT installed as an alternative to modify and compile the "platform-specific code" that Cordova generates within platforms/android.

Source - [Cordova Docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_build_the_app)

So, when you have made a slight modification in a .java file (which is an android platform specific file) and tried to rebuild it within Eclipse, you were actually trying to rebuild the same project without any actual modifications.

Another alternative would be to copy the files within the ***project/www/*** to ***project/platforms/android/assets/www/*** by hand and then build it within Eclipse, which would, of course, be an unnecessary pain.