# phonegap/android: changes to index.html not being regarded when building the app

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm making my first steps in phonegap. I've been able to set up a project, install a plugin and build the app on my phone without errors. However, now, when I try to change the layout of my `www/index.html` in the project's root `platforms/android/assets/www/index.html` stays untouched whenever I (re)build the app.
I'm basically working in eclipse, only for html and javascript I use sublime. I've searched now for a couple of hours for a solution. The most promising approach was this thread: [Changes to HTML files not showing on built phonegap 3.0 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445290/changes-to-html-files-not-showing-on-built-phonegap-3-0-app) ... but even that didn't work.

What can I have done wrong? There's no error, no warning (none resulting from the build process) and I don't know how I could debug the issue. I'm currently using phonegap/cordova 4.2.0

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason for my problem. However, installing the app via cordova CLI rather than eclipse seems to have solved the problem:

```
$ cordova prepare android
$ cordova run android
```